# Facebook SDK 3.0 session

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I have try to switch to new Facebook SDK 3.0
But i have some problem with FBSession
Main goal:
User must login once.
Then User can post something on his wall 
But, the session expiration date can't be more than 60 days.
I dont want disturb user to login again.
I need just extend FBSession.

In old FB SDK 2.0 was function 
- (void)extendAccessTokenIfNeeded;

But how extend FBSession in SDK 3.0?

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the old SDK you would have to extend the access token yourself. The 3.1 (and 3.0) extends it for you in the background whenever it needs to and usually alongside a request you make.